# How to return 404 with Spring WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I'm having a controller like this one (in Kotlin):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
class CustomerController (private val service: CustomerService) {
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    fun findById(@PathVariable id: String,
                 @RequestHeader(value = IF_NONE_MATCH) versionHeader: String?): Mono<HttpEntity<KundeResource>> =
        return service.findById(id)
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(NotFoundException()))
            .map {
                // ETag stuff ...
                ok().eTag("...").body(...)
            }
}
```

Im wondering whether there is a better approach than throwing an exception which is annotated with `@ResponseStatus(code = NOT_FOUND)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of throwing an exception the method's implementation can be changed to

```
fun findById(@PathVariable id: String,
             @RequestHeader(value = IF_NONE_MATCH) versionHeader: String?): Mono<ResponseEntity<KundeResource>> =
    return service.findById(id)
        .map {
            // ETag stuff ...
            ok().eTag("...").body(...)
        }
        .defaultIfEmpty(notFound().build())
```

Answer (score 8):

I would like use `RouteFunction` instead of @RestController when Spring 5 is stable. Define a HandlerFunction to handle request, and then declare a `RouteFunction` to map request to the HandlerFunction:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> get(ServerRequest req) {
    return this.posts
        .findById(req.pathVariable("id"))
        .flatMap((post) -> ServerResponse.ok().body(Mono.just(post), Post.class))
        .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
}
```

Check the complete example codes [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/routes).

Kotlin version, define a function to handle request,  the use `RouteFunctionDSL` to map incoming request to HandlerFuncation:

```
fun get(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> {
    return this.posts.findById(req.pathVariable("id"))
            .flatMap { post -> ok().body(Mono.just(post), Post::class.java) }
            .switchIfEmpty(notFound().build())
}
```

It is can be an expression, like:

```
fun get(req: ServerRequest): Mono<ServerResponse> = this.posts.findById(req.pathVariable("id"))
            .flatMap { post -> ok().body(Mono.just(post), Post::class.java) }
            .switchIfEmpty(notFound().build())
```

Check the complete example codes of Kotlin DSL [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/kotlin-dsl).

If you prefer traditional controllers to expose REST APIs, try this approach.

Firstly define an exception, eg. `PostNotFoundException`. Then throw it in controller.

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public Mono<Post> get(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        return this.posts.findById(id).switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new PostNotFoundException(id)));
    }
```

Define an `ExceptionHandler` to handle the exception, and register it in `HttpHandler`.

```
@Profile("default")
@Bean
public NettyContext nettyContext(ApplicationContext context) {
    HttpHandler handler = WebHttpHandlerBuilder.applicationContext(context)
        .exceptionHandler(exceptionHandler())
        .build();
    ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter adapter = new ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter(handler);
    HttpServer httpServer = HttpServer.create("localhost", this.port);
    return httpServer.newHandler(adapter).block();
}

@Bean
public WebExceptionHandler exceptionHandler() {
    return (ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) -> {
        if (ex instanceof PostNotFoundException) {
            exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        }
        return Mono.error(ex);
    };
}
```

Check the [complete codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/exception-handler) here. For Spring Boot users, check [this sample](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/tree/master/boot-exception-handler).

**Update**：In the latest spring 5.2, I found the general `@RestControllerAdvice`
works for controllers in webflux applications.

Comment: On your GitHub sample code here: https://github.com/hantsy/spring-reactive-sample/blob/master/routes/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostHandler.java   for the create method everything works fine but when the request body is empty it returns an HTTP 200 ?!!! Any Suggestions

Comment: Add validation for the request body, see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48031647/what-is-the-best-way-to-validate-request-in-a-spring-webflux-functional-applicat, I hope there are official solutions for this.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [ResponseStatusException](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ResponseStatusException.html), just extend your exception:

```
public class YourLogicException extends ResponseStatusException {

public YourLogicException(String message) {
    super(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, message);
}

public YourLogicException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, message, cause);
}
```

And in service:

```
public Mono<String> doLogic(Mono<YourContext> ctx) {
    return ctx.map(ctx -> doSomething(ctx));
}

private String doSomething(YourContext ctx) {
    try {
        // some logic
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new YourLogicException("Exception message", e);
    }
}
```

And after that, you could have a pretty message:

```
 { "timestamp": 00000000, "path": "/endpoint", "status": 404, "error": "Not found", "message": "Exception message" }
```